# React-Select if value exists show value if not show placeholder text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-select

I'm using this component here: https://react-select.com/home

What I'm trying to accomplish is on page load if my array contains a value in my `Assigned` element then I want to display that by default in my `react-select` box if not then I want my placeholder `Assign to` to show.

Here is how my select looks:

```
<Select
    value={this.state.Product[0].Assigned ? this.state.Product[0].Assigned : selectedAssigned}
    onChange={this.handleChangeAssigned}
    options={this.state.AssignedList}
    placeholder={<div>Assign to:</div>}
/>
```

In my `Product[0].Assigned` there is currently a value, however the dropdown still has the placeholder `Assign To`. I tried changing value to `value={this.state.Product[0].Assigned}` but still no luck.

Here is my change handle:

```
handleChangeAssigned = selectedAssigned => {
    this.setState(
      { selectedAssigned },
      () => console.log(`Option selected:`, this.state.selectedAssigned)
    );
  };
```

Comment: Do you mean `this.state.Assigned[0]`?

Comment: @jdaz No I have an array called `Array` i know the name suckss

Comment: That is a bad idea because `Array` is a Javascript global object name, you will get weird bugs.

Comment: @jdaz thank you for the heads up. I'll change that now. Any idea how I can fix this placeholder issue?

Comment: React does not track deep changes in state.
`this.state.Array[0].Assigned`
How you change the state?

Comment: @AlexanderAlexandrov I updated my question with the change handle. So basically I have this dropdown. When they select I'm storing it in my database. When they load this page again I have this array `this.state.Array[0].Assigned` if this has a value I want to display that if not to display the placeholder.

Comment: Sorry, I can get the point. How `this.state.Array[0]` is fulfilled. By `useEffect` or something? If there are currently a value (as you said above) than how `this.state.UserList[0].Product` is fulfilled?

Comment: @AlexanderAlexandrov Sorry for the type, check again. So `this.state.Product[0].Assigned` currently has a value of `John Doe` I want to show that name instead of `Assign To`.

Comment: Could you please show the part of your code wich loads data into Product

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are storing the same data in multiple places.  You are checking if you have an assignment by looking at `this.state.Product[0].Assigned`.  But when you select an assignment you are not updating that property.  Instead you are updating a completely separate property `this.state.selectedAssigned`.  `this.state.Product[0].Assigned` never changes so if you see a placeholder at first then you will always see a placeholder.

The `value` that you set on the `Select` needs to be the same as the value that you update.

```
import React from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

interface Option {
  label: string;
  value: string;
}

interface State {
  Product: any[];
  AssignedList: Option[];
  selectedAssigned: Option | null;
}

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component<{}, State> {
  state: State = {
    Product: [],
    AssignedList: [
      { label: "a", value: "a" },
      { label: "b", value: "b" },
      { label: "c", value: "c" }
    ],
    selectedAssigned: null
  };

  handleChangeAssigned = (selectedAssigned: Option | null) => {
    this.setState({ selectedAssigned }, () =>
      console.log(`Option selected:`, this.state.selectedAssigned)
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Select
        value={this.state.selectedAssigned}
        onChange={this.handleChangeAssigned}
        options={this.state.AssignedList}
        placeholder={<div>Assign to:</div>}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

[Code Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-river-01m3o?file=/src/App.tsx)